# TypeScript Extending Map Class - TypeError: Constructor Map requires 'new'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
/** A collection of Collection objects. */
export default class Collection<T> extends Map {
  set: any;
  clear: any;
  delete: any;

  constructor(connections: any[]) {
    super();

    for (let item of connections)
      this.set(item.id, item as T);
  }

  /** Convert collection to array. */
  array(): T[] {
    return Array.from(this.values());
  }
}
```

```js
/** A collection of Collection objects. */
class Collection extends Map {

  constructor(connections) {
    super();

    for (let item of connections)
      this.set(item.id, item);
  }

  /** Convert collection to array. */
  array() {
    return Array.from(this.values());
  }
}

let test = new Collection([{id: 1}, {id: 2}])
console.log([...test.entries()])
```

I am trying to extend a map class with a few additional functions.

`new Collection<Guild>(response.body);`
seems to give the error `TypeError: Constructor Map requires 'new'`.

How could this be fixed?

Comment: You showed `Connections` class but calls `Collections`.

Comment: Typo has been fixed. Thanks.

Comment: What is `Guild`?

Comment: I assume you changed `export default class Collection<T> extends Map {` to `export default class Collection<T> extends new Map() {` or `export default class Collection<T> extends new Map {` both to no avail right?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAKgHzTIAeay2AJjALJgAO0A3gFDTQTJoBc0Y2AJ4BudtFDIwAJz4CRYqshQVZQ0WOA4IaKQFd08KQApN2bKkxbVggNoBdAJQsxHCLobJjD9Rw4AzQ2gjZWgMCgBbaHg-cRxzdCxsCAcXXzQACwwIADouNCMw5HDsjCoAGlCI-hh8bzEAX1YxAHoAKla4HAA3TzRYpAtE6DR4fikpMEFs6FbmsWkJwSMHPnx7Z19oKW5dKWxoAEFxyey-KXhwowys7K6wEF1kCGW6jkbG1lNtUKS0AWBkNAALzQcwAd06AwSOCM9jqny0iGQ2RA8AA5kYAER+DDYLLpZBUTEOIA)

Comment: https://github.com/twopg/OAuth/blob/stable/src/client.ts#L132